# Cannot delete row from MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, delete-row

I've got a table, which won't delete a row. Specifically, when I try to delete any row with a GEO_SHAPE_ID over 150000000 it simply does not disappear from the DB.

I have tried:

1. SQLyog to erase it.
2. *DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE
   GEO_SHAPE_ID = 150000042* (0 rows
   affected).
3. *UNLOCK TABLES* then 2.

As far as I am aware, bigint is a valid candidate for auto_increment. Anyone know what could be up?
Whenever I perform any of the above operations and refresh the table listing, the row re-appears.
You gotta help us, Doc. We’ve tried nothin’ and we’re all out of ideas!

DJS.

EDIT: as per Daniel Vassallo's suggestion:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `GEO_SHAPE` WHERE GEO_SHAPE_ID = 150000042;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

ANSWER: After discovering the 'check' and 'repair' commands in MySQL, I found corrupt keys, so fixed those and it worked.

PS. Here is the table construct and some sample data just for giggles.

```
CREATE TABLE `GEO_SHAPE` (
  `GEO_SHAPE_ID` bigint(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `RADIUS` float default '0',
  `LATITUDE` float default '0',
  `LONGITUDE` float default '0',
  `SHAPE_TYPE` enum('Custom','Region') default NULL,
  `PARENT_ID` int(11) default NULL,
  `SHAPE_POLYGON` polygon default NULL,
  `SHAPE_TITLE` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `SHAPE_ABBREVIATION` varchar(45) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`GEO_SHAPE_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=150000056 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

LOCK TABLES `GEO_SHAPE` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `GEO_SHAPE` (`GEO_SHAPE_ID`, `RADIUS`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE`, `SHAPE_TYPE`, `PARENT_ID`, `SHAPE_POLYGON`, `SHAPE_TITLE`, `SHAPE_ABBREVIATION`) VALUES (57, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Region', 10, NULL, 'Washington', 'WA');
INSERT INTO `GEO_SHAPE` (`GEO_SHAPE_ID`, `RADIUS`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE`, `SHAPE_TYPE`, `PARENT_ID`, `SHAPE_POLYGON`, `SHAPE_TITLE`, `SHAPE_ABBREVIATION`) VALUES (58, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Region', 10, NULL, 'West Virginia', 'WV');
INSERT INTO `GEO_SHAPE` (`GEO_SHAPE_ID`, `RADIUS`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE`, `SHAPE_TYPE`, `PARENT_ID`, `SHAPE_POLYGON`, `SHAPE_TITLE`, `SHAPE_ABBREVIATION`) VALUES (59, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Region', 10, NULL, 'Wisconsin', 'WI');
INSERT INTO `GEO_SHAPE` (`GEO_SHAPE_ID`, `RADIUS`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE`, `SHAPE_TYPE`, `PARENT_ID`, `SHAPE_POLYGON`, `SHAPE_TITLE`, `SHAPE_ABBREVIATION`) VALUES (150000042, 10, -33.8833, 151.217, 'Custom', NULL, NULL, 'Sydney%2C%20New%20South%20Wales%20%2810km%20r', NULL);
INSERT INTO `GEO_SHAPE` (`GEO_SHAPE_ID`, `RADIUS`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE`, `SHAPE_TYPE`, `PARENT_ID`, `SHAPE_POLYGON`, `SHAPE_TITLE`, `SHAPE_ABBREVIATION`) VALUES (150000043, 10, -33.8833, 151.167, 'Custom', NULL, NULL, 'Annandale%2C%20New%20South%20Wales%20%2810km%', NULL);
INSERT INTO `GEO_SHAPE` (`GEO_SHAPE_ID`, `RADIUS`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE`, `SHAPE_TYPE`, `PARENT_ID`, `SHAPE_POLYGON`, `SHAPE_TITLE`, `SHAPE_ABBREVIATION`) VALUES (150000048, 10, -27.5, 153.017, 'Custom', NULL, NULL, 'Brisbane%2C%20Queensland%20%2810km%20radius%2', NULL);
INSERT INTO `GEO_SHAPE` (`GEO_SHAPE_ID`, `RADIUS`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE`, `SHAPE_TYPE`, `PARENT_ID`, `SHAPE_POLYGON`, `SHAPE_TITLE`, `SHAPE_ABBREVIATION`) VALUES (150000045, 10, 43.1002, -75.2956, 'Custom', NULL, NULL, 'New%20York%20Mills%2C%20New%20York%20%2810km%', NULL);
INSERT INTO `GEO_SHAPE` (`GEO_SHAPE_ID`, `RADIUS`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE`, `SHAPE_TYPE`, `PARENT_ID`, `SHAPE_POLYGON`, `SHAPE_TITLE`, `SHAPE_ABBREVIATION`) VALUES (150000046, 10, 40.1117, -78.9258, 'Custom', NULL, NULL, 'Region1', NULL);
UNLOCK TABLES;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was a corrupt table. I fixed this with 'CHECK TABLE GEO_SHAPE;' and then 'REPAIR TABLE GEO_SHAPE;

Answer (score 4):

Go to the `Console`, in the top-right corner of Sequel Pro. Right-click on the command that failed to run and copy it.

Paste it into the `Query` section at the top of Sequel Pro and run it manually.

That will allow you to see the error that is preventing the row from being deleted and fix it.

Comment: Thank you! helped me find a foreign-key constraint that was preventing deletion.

Answer (score 3):

Just tried it with your data, and it worked as expected:

```
DELETE FROM `GEO_SHAPE` WHERE GEO_SHAPE_ID = 150000042;
-- Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Result:

```
+--------------+--------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| GEO_SHAPE_ID | RADIUS | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE | SHAPE_TYPE | PARENT_ID | SHAPE_POLYGON | SHAPE_TITLE                                   | SHAPE_ABBREVIATION |
+--------------+--------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|           57 |   NULL |     NULL |      NULL | Region     |        10 | NULL          | Washington                                    | WA                 | 
|           58 |   NULL |     NULL |      NULL | Region     |        10 | NULL          | West Virginia                                 | WV                 | 
|           59 |   NULL |     NULL |      NULL | Region     |        10 | NULL          | Wisconsin                                     | WI                 | 
|    150000043 |     10 | -33.8833 |   151.167 | Custom     |      NULL | NULL          | Annandale%2C%20New%20South%20Wales%20%2810km% | NULL               | 
|    150000048 |     10 |    -27.5 |   153.017 | Custom     |      NULL | NULL          | Brisbane%2C%20Queensland%20%2810km%20radius%2 | NULL               | 
|    150000045 |     10 |  43.1002 |  -75.2956 | Custom     |      NULL | NULL          | New%20York%20Mills%2C%20New%20York%20%2810km% | NULL               | 
|    150000046 |     10 |  40.1117 |  -78.9258 | Custom     |      NULL | NULL          | Region1                                       | NULL               | 
+--------------+--------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Did you try:

```
SELECT * FROM `GEO_SHAPE` WHERE GEO_SHAPE_ID = 150000042;
```

Comment: @Wilhelm: Hehe, true... My intention was to show that it looks like the problem is somewhere else, because this is expected to work as intended.

Comment: Ah-ha! A clue... 
    mysql> SELECT * FROM `GEO_SHAPE` WHERE GEO_SHAPE_ID = 150000042;
Empty set (0.01 sec)